# What does これには mean in this sentence?

Tags: particle-に, particle-は

「私って元来遊び人なのかもと妙に納得しつつ、もう一つ新たに開設された「脳内フェチイメージ」にチャレンジしたら、これには腰を抜かさんばかりの驚きでありました。」's「これには」

Comment: こういう質問**には**いつもがっかりです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これ indicates 脳内フェチイメージ and に is a marker that tells これ is what the speaker was surprised at. は is a usual topic marker (as far as we can read).